# 2 laptop drives into powered usb3 hub

Tags: windows-10, usb-3, usb-hub

I'm trying to connect 2 2.5" laptop drives (both are mechanical) to a USB3 hub.

I've tried with 2 different USB3 hubs - both have power adapters. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to tell if they are powering or not... however these are 2 different hubs with 2 different respective adapters. So my guess is something else is going on.

When I plug the drives into my laptop directly into USB 3 ports, they can work simultaneously without problems.

But what I want to do is to plug them both into the hub which is plugged into one usb3 port on the laptop.

And with both powered hubs, I cannot access them simultaneously that way. Weird things happen. Sometimes one of the drives will lock up explorer when accessed, for example.

Is this not really advised? I figured if the hub is powered then it would be ok.

If I have 2 usb3 flash drives in the hub at the same time, they will work and not affect things. The problem is just when the 2 mechanical drives are both plugged in. Just to be clear. It doesn't matter which of the 2 usb 3.0 hubs (w/power adapter) that I use.

Comment: What are the specs of the power supplies for the hubs, and what model 2.5" disk drives ?  Maybe they are not providing enough current to drive the 2 drives you are using - a typical hard drive requires about 1 amp - sometimes a little more (at 5 volts) - so if you are running 2 drives + the hub circuitry the power supply might not be up to it.

Comment: 2A 5V..can I just order a 5V power supply with more amps?

Comment: That depends on your USB hub - I'd imagine so, but can't guarantee it.  I'd also imagine that 2A @ 5 volts is marginal and that would explain your problem.

Comment: i'll give it a try - I guess I never had such problems before because I used to use 3.5" external drives (which have their own power adapters)